# Registering formular that doesn't flush. Symfony 2.5.6

Tags: php, symfony

I have e little problem. I followed this tutorial to create a register formular but it doesn't persist the entity. I don't understand why. It doesn't create any mistake, it just... doesn't flush.

Here is the tutorial:
http://symfony.com/fr/doc/2.5/cookbook/doctrine/registration_form.html

Here is the entity:

```
namespace theia\mainBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * UserMain
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="theia\mainBundle\Entity\UserMainRepository")
 */
class UserMain
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="roles", type="array")
     */
    private $roles;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return UserMain
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set password
     *
     * @param string $password
     * @return UserMain
     */
    public function setPassword($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get password
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Set roles
     *
     * @param array $roles
     * @return UserMain
     */
    public function setRoles($roles)
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get roles
     *
     * @return array 
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->roles = [ 'ROLE_USER' ];

    }
}
```

here is my "Security Controller":

```
namespace theia\mainBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

use theia\mainBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationType;
use theia\mainBundle\Form\Model\Registration;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{

    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        $session = $request->getSession();
        if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $error = $request->attributes->get(
                SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTIFICATION_ERROR
            );
        } elseif (null !== $session && $session->has(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
             $error = $session->get(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
             $session->remove(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        } else {
            $error = null;
        }

    // last username entered by the user
        $lastEmail = (null === $session) ? '' : $session->get(SecurityContextInterface::LAST_USERNAME);

        return $this->render(
            'theiamainBundle::security/login.html.twig',
            array(
                // last username entered by the user
                'last_email' => $lastEmail,
                'error'         => $error,
            )
        );
    }

    public function loginCheckAction()
    {
    }

    public function logoutAction()
    {
    }

    public function registerAction()
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new RegistrationType(), new Registration());

        return $this->render('theiamainBundle:security:register.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
    }

    public function createAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

        $form = $this->createForm(new RegistrationType(), new Registration());

        $form->handleRequest($this->getRequest());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $registration = $form->getData();

            $em->persist($registration->getUser());
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect('theiamainBundle::security/login.html.twig');
        }

        return $this->render('theiamainBundle:security:register.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
    }
}
```

Here is what is in the directory Form:
My UserMainType:

```
namespace theia\mainBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class UsermainType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('email', 'email');
        $builder->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
           'first_name' => 'password',
           'second_name' => 'confirm',
           'type' => 'password',
        ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'theia\mainBundle\Entity\UserMain'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }
}
```

Here is the RegistrationType

```
namespace theia\mainBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('user', new UsermainType());
        //$builder->add('terms', 'checkbox', array('property_path' => 'termsAccepted'));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'registration';
    }
}
```

Here is Registration

```
namespace theia\mainBundle\Form\Model;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

use theia\mainBundle\Entity\UserMain;

class Registration
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Type(type="theia\mainBundle\Entity\User")
     */
    protected $user;

    /*
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @Assert\True()
     *
    protected $termsAccepted;
*/
    public function setUser(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }


    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
/*
    public function getTermsAccepted()
    {
        return $this->termsAccepted;
    }

    public function setTermsAccepted($termsAccepted)
    {
        $this->termsAccepted = (Boolean) $termsAccepted;
    }
*/
}
```

Thanks you for your helps

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure but I think the problem is that you haven't set

```
'data_class' => 'theia\mainBundle\Entity\Registration'
```

In the `setDefaultOptions` of your RegistrationType, therefore the RegistrationType will not be mapped to an entity, therefore the UserMain cannot be persisted since it is used in the subform of RegistrationType.